# Or Conditions in Xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I would like to find the Xpath, where the Text contains two names. I want my xpath to identify any one of the conditions below.

e.g

```
//div[text()='USER NAME' OR text()='USER ID']
```

or

```
//div[text()='USER NAME' | text()='USER ID']
```

Can i use like above, Actually both are not working. Please help me with identification.

Answer (score 2):

XPath definitely supports [OR expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr).  It is also case-sensitive.  Use `text()` rather than `TEXT()` and `or` rather than `OR`.  You didn't show us the HTML fragment, so I can't tell whether you really want 'USER NAME' or 'user name' or 'User name'.  You will have to figure that out for yourself.

Try this:

```
 //div[text()='USER NAME' or text()='USER ID']
```

When you run into problems like this, go the web page you are interested in and open up the browser debugger.  You can probably experiment with XPath expressions there.  In the Chrome debugger, you can use

`$x(expression goes here)`,

e.g.

```
$x("//div[text()='USER NAME' or text()='USER ID']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contains` in the xpath with the common *String* is `USER`
 like this

```
 xpath=//div[contains(@title,"title")]
```

Here's the link to know more-http://automationtricks.blogspot.in/search/label/xpath

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the approach you are taking may need reevaluation.

A test needs to be repeatable.  You should therefore be able to replicate the conditions where the ID is returned and also when the Name is.

As such, I would recommend that instead of using an OR, you should instead have 2 separate tests that assert each condition independently.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can use OR condition such as `//a[text()='Or Conditions in ' | text()='Xpath']` but as I understand your requirements, I would suggest using contains.

Your second xpath should work. Please check your text's case. Xpath is case sensitive so `or conditions in` is not the same as `Or Conditions in`